# por que no me imprime $_SESSION["user"]?

Tags: php, html, mysql, vue.js

Estoy realizando el login, pero por alguna razon a la hora de redireccionarme a la pagina no me imprime el usuario, aqui el codigo:

php:

```
public static function login () {
    
    $user = Clear::Clearvars($_POST["user"]);
    $pass = Clear::Clearvars($_POST["pass"]);
    $query = Model::login($user, $pass);

    self::start_session($query);
    header("Location:index.php?url=admin_panel");
}

 public static function start_session($query) {
    setcookie("user",$query["user"],time()+(60*2));
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $query["user"];
}

 public static function login ($user, $pass) {
    $query = self::connect()->prepare("SELECT * FROM `admin` WHERE `user`=:user and `pass`=:pass");
    $query->execute(["user" => $user,"pass"  => $pass]);
    return $query = ($query->rowCount() == 1) ? $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) : 0;
    
}
```

aqui la vista:

```
   <section class = "admin_panel">
        <h1>Welcome admin:<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION["user"];?></h1>
        <button class = "admin_button" @click = "register_new_product">Register new product</button>
        <button class = "admin_button"@click = "package_new_product">Package new product</button>
        <button class = "admin_button"@click = "see_actual_products">See actual products</button>
        <button class = "admin_button"@click = "finished_products">Finished products</button>
        <button class = "admin_button"@click = "wainting_products">Wainting products</button>
        <button class = "admin_button" @click = "logout" type="button">Logout</button>
    </section>
```

no me imprime es por algo de las rutas de los archivos pero no lo tengo muy en claro y creo que eso no deberia ser motivo para que no se imprima, aqui les dejo el codigo de route para que vean como se renderiza la vista:

```
Routes::set("admin_panel",function() {  
ControllerView::renderview('admin_panel');
});

public static function renderview($view) { 

    $view = Clear::ClearVars($view);
    $content = self::getcontent($view);

    echo $content;
}
```

Comment: Activa el reporte de errores para ver si aparece un mensaje `headers already sent`. Lo que hace `session_start();` es enviar encabezados al navegador para crear una cookie que permita a PHP identificar la conexión, pero no funciona cuando ya enviaste contenido al navegador (espacio, salto de línea, 1 caracter, HTML, etc.) porque, junto con esa primera salida, se enviaron encabezados para que el navegador trate de identificar el contenido que va a recibir.

Comment: Siempre coloca `session_start();` al inicio de la petición, antes de cualquier otra salida para que PHP _conecte con el navegador_. Lo que hagas después con las variables de sesión es lo que te ayudará a identificar usuarios.